# launchctl getenv command returns an empty PATH

Tags: macos, launchctl

When I run

```
launchctl getenv PATH
```

in the terminal, I always get an empty string as a response.  I tried using

```
sudo launchctl getenv PATH
```

since with `sudo`, the system environment is queried, but I still get an empty string.  Am I missing something ?   Shouldn't that return my PATH or at least, the system PATH ?  Something like

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I have looked at many answers here and they all seem to imply that the original command should return a path and not nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Answering a super old question here, but I just had the same issue and fixed it.

My system had XQuartz deactivated from system settings --> "Login Items", Once reactivated it was working again after a system restart.

Anyone else coming across this, make sure you're not blocking XQuartz.

You can also test if it is running by entering "xeyes" in your terminal - should open a little funny set of eyes if everything is set correctly.